# Advertising network with keyword API

Tags: api, ads

I have some pages that can't be indexed (so I can't use adsense and the like) but I still want ads there based on keywords that I have extracted from what I know about my users. Lets say a user has a lot activity about TV's so I show him a custom TV ad after sending in the keyword "TV" to a Advertising network API. Are there any such Advertising network services? Remember that the pages can't be index by the Advertising network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retiligence is what I was looking for. http://www.retailigence.com/developers/